# Visual Studio 2015 C# Deploy Application to Desktop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, clickonce

I have a C# application. It has multiple forms and multiple classes. I've been looking for ages on how to deploy my application and keep running into issues.

I've tried:

#### ClickOnce

Right click on my solution -> Publish

This is the data I've entered:

```
Specify the location to publish this application:

    C:\Users\$USER\Desktop

How will users install the application?
```

Here I just want to be able to get an installation file that will install the app and all the assets. This is purely for testing, but I just want to be able to send a friend the .exe install via email (or some other means) so they can play around with it. I have not gotten any of these options to work thus can't continue.

#### File -> New Project -> Other Project Types -> Visual Studio Installer -> Setup Project

I right click on `Application folder -> add -> Project Output`

When doing this, it tells me I need to close my current solution (my application) and if I want to save. It looks like other people are able to get this project output project to show in the solution explorer along with their main application, but I can't seem to do that.

The entire `Add Project Output Group` is empty, including both dropdowns.

---

These are the two methods I've seen that seem to be the easiest, but I can't even seem to get them to work :s

---

I do also have my own website, and eventually I'd like users to install the application from a page on the website. If easier, I could set that up instead of dealing with just getting an install file, but I haven't looked into it as I assumed just getting this install file on my computer would be simpler.

Any help with this would be highly appreciated as I'm lost as of now.

Answer (score 0):

So when I share my work with my a friend to review, what i generally do is send him them the `.exe` located in `bin\Debug\app.publish\<name>.exe` folder inside the project folder. Take care to place all the `.dll`, i.e class libraries that you have written into that folder, zip it, and share! Your friend should be able to extract and run.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but where can I find the ```.dll``` files? Inside the app.publish folder only exists the .exe, and in the other folders I can't seem to find any ```.dll``` files. Thank you.

Comment: You want to look in `bin\Debug` and move any `.dll` s to the `app.publish` sub folder.

Comment: It doens't seem like I have any. Also when I try and run the .exe in the ```app.publish``` folder, it can't locate any of the assets (images) I have. I assume this would be since I don't have any ```.dll```'s?

Comment: Have you tried including the images you use in the same folder as the .exe? You might have to change your filepaths to use the local context if need be.